# Confusion regarding fwrite() and fread() parameters in C

Tags: c, function, fwrite

I am new to C and recently i have been working on a program whereby i am reading a stream of 512 bytes from a file using fread into a array and then after checking for certain conditions in that stream of bytes i am writing the stream of bytes into a new file using fwrite.
The code snippet for the same is

```
    unsigned char buffer[512];
    FILE *fp = fopen("file.name","r");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening the file\n ");
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }

    while(fread(&buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1 , fp) == 1) //my program works fine for both &buffer and only buffer
    {
          //Do something
    }
```

The definition of fread is:

```
    size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
```

Here ptr is the  pointer to a block of memory where the read bytes will be stored.

I have defined buffer to be a character array and hence only passing `buffer` as the first parameter should have been enough as it is a pointer but the program works fine even when `&buffer` is being provided. The same is happening with fwrite as well. Now if `buffer` is the pointer then `&buffer` is the address of the pointer and should not have the same result as that of a pointer but it actually does, **so why does the function work properly with both the different parameters?**

Comment: They point to the same address.

Comment: `&buffer` is *not* the "address of the pointer". That statement doesn't even make sense. There is no "the pointer".

Comment: Also note that your function will only read blocks of 512 bytes. If your file size isn't a multiple of that, you won't be able to read the remainder.

Comment: Best answer from the link Jon cites: "That's because the array name (my_array) is different from a pointer to array. It is an alias to the address of an array, and its address is defined as the address of the array itself."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, any data-pointer type is implicitly convertible to `void*`:

- `buffer` designates the array. It is not a pointer. Arrays are in nearly all contexts converted to a pointer to their first elements though.
- `&buffer` this is one of the exceptions, so here we have a pointer to said array instead.

Anyway, you probably want to do this instead:

```
size_t count;
while((count = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fp)) > 0)
```

Why?

- Because you want to read **all** the data, and not miss the final partial block.
- On an interactive device you want to act on the data as early as possible, not waiting until a full `sizeof(buffer)` block is done.

Comment: +1 Proper type and use of `size_t count`